# Boost.Asio socket is being blocked

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The for loop in main.cpp, which calls a function that uses boost::mutex and that reads from a socket using read_until, only runs once, after that it's like it's blocked. I've tried putting a continue before the closing brackets and then it crashes. It's probably related to threading.

```
// MAIN.CPP

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    std::cout << "Enter port number: ";
    std::string port;
    std::getline(std::cin, port);
    int tempPort = std::stoi(port);
    Network * network = new Network(tempPort);

    int it = 0;
    boost::thread * t1;
    t1 = new boost::thread([&network, &it]
    {
        while (true)
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket * sock = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(network->io_service);
            network->accept(*sock);

            if (network->socketList.size() > 0)
            {
                for (boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket * s : network->socketList)
                {
                    if (s->remote_endpoint().address().to_string() == sock->remote_endpoint().address().to_string())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        network->socketList.push_back(sock);
                        std::cout << s->remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << " connected." << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                network->socketList.push_back(sock);
                std::cout << sock->remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << " connected." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    });

    while (true)
    {
        for (boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket * sock : network->socketList)
        {
            std::cout << "on range-based for loop" << std::endl;
            network->readChatMessage(*(sock));
        }
    }
    t1->join();

    return 0;
}

// NETWORK.CPP
int Network::sendChatMessage(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & socket, ChatMessage & message)
{
    try
    {
        boost::system::error_code err;

        boost::asio::streambuf buf;
        {
            std::ostream out(&buf);
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(out);
            oa & message;

            std::cout << std::string(message.text.begin(), message.text.end()) << std::endl;
        }

        m.lock();
        write(socket, buf, err);

        if (err)
        {
            std::cout << err.message() << std::endl;
        }

        m.unlock();

        std::cout << "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int Network::readChatMessage(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & socket)
{
    std::cout << "in readChatMessage()" << std::endl;

    boost::system::error_code err;

    boost::asio::streambuf buf;

    m.lock();
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, '\0', err);

    if (err)
    {
        std::cout << err.message() << std::endl;
    }

    m.unlock();

    std::istream in(&buf);
    ChatMessage message;

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(in);
    ia & message;

    std::cout << std::string(message.text.begin(), message.text.end()) << std::endl;
    this->sendChatMessage(socket, message);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've spent 6 minutes trying to figure out a subset of the program that is complete. Can you make it SSCCE? Why is everything using `new`?

Comment: This might not be related, but it seems to me that your program will never exit -- you join the thread, but I fail to see any way how the thread function can exit (nicely, as in not with some uncaught exception).

Comment: +1 on the question about `new`. Also, if you need to have dynamically allocated objects, why not at least use smart pointers? This is just asking for memory leaks for no good reason at all. | If it crashes, then where? Use debugger to find more. | In `readChatMessage`, why do you try to deserialize and process the message when the read fails? | `scoped_lock` or something like that might be useful too. Use RAII.

Comment: I'm leaving for a few hours, got to do some things, I'll provide an compilable example later today.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem after debugging and editing the code a bit, then I was able to see there was an error happening: `input stream error` due to the serialization Input/Output. I handled the error properly, unlocking the mutex when the error happened and not letting the mutex go undone.

Snippet:

```
int Network::readChatMessage(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket & socket)
{
    std::cout << "in readChatMessage()" << std::endl;

    boost::system::error_code err;

    boost::asio::streambuf buf;

    m.lock();
    boost::asio::read_until(socket, buf, '\0', err);

    if (err)
    {
        m.unlock();
        std::cout << err.message() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {

        m.unlock();

        std::istream in(&buf);
        ChatMessage message;

        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(in);
        ia & message;

        std::cout << std::string(message.text.begin(), message.text.end()) << std::endl;
        this->sendChatMessage(socket, message);
        return 0;
    } 
    m.unlock();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For future reference, you should really be using either a [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) (STL/C++11) or a [`scoped_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/scoped_lock.html) (boost) to handle your mutexes, as it would have prevented this issue in the first place had you done so.

Comment: @Xirema Thanks, that worked very well, and it fixed a crashing when many messages were being sent at the same time! :)